# Encrypting text using Caeser cipher in CFB mode

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, cfb

I am interested in learning and understanding cryptography and its application in every day life. One thing I can't seem to get my head around is encrypting plaintext using a block mode such as CFB. I want to use a Caesar block cipher in CFB mode to encrypt the following plaintext: `lucozade` with a key: `3`.

So in this case, I get that using the Caeser block cipher the ciphertext for `lucozade` would be `oxfrcdgh` as the letters have shifted three places to the right. What I can't do is this encryption using CFB mode. How do I go about doing that? Like would I have to use the ciphertext `oxfrcdgh` as the IV?

Any help would be great

Comment: Ceaser cipher has nothing to do with CFB mode.

Comment: @kelalaka so how do I encrypt the plaintext using caeser block cipher in cfb mode???

Comment: @kelalaka lol how do I do that? that's the question. like I'm lost as to what I should be doing first. Do I use the output of the caeser cipher in the cfb? Would be amazing if you could answer my question - honestly make my day. I'm trying to self learn so sorry if I am a bit stupid

Comment: Is this an exercise in some textbook or online tutorial? I'm asking because, while one *can* define something analogous to [CFB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) with a Caesar cipher in place of the block cipher, and while doing so could be a useful educational exercise, the result will be a) completely insecure for any practical purpose, and also b) not well defined unless you also specify a replacement for the bitwise XOR operation that will work on the Caesar cipher alphabet (which is doable, but there's more than one option to choose from).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah it was from some old textbook exercises. how would i encrypt the plaintext `lucozade` using the caeser block cipher in cfb mode??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Caesar cipher

You are confusing Caesar cipher with block ciphers.

In Caesar cipher the ciphertext is calculated as

$$c_i = p_i + 3 \bmod 26$$

There is no security in Caesar Cipher. A ciphertext only attack possible, as worst scenario.

### CFB Caesar cipher

$c_i = c_{i-1} + 3 + p_i \bmod 26 $, with $c_0 = IV$

And, the **decryption**;

$p_i = c_i - 3 -c_{i-1} \bmod 26 $, with $c_0 = IV$

Example : $P=lucozade = \{11,20,2,14,25,0,3,4\}$

Let choose $IV = f = 5$

\begin{align}
  c_1 &\equiv IV + 3 + p_1 \bmod 26 \equiv 5 + 3 + 11 \bmod 26 \equiv 19 \text { that is } T\\
  c_2 &\equiv c_1 + 3 + p_2 \bmod 26 \equiv 19 + 3 + 20 \bmod 26 \equiv 16 \text { that is } Q\\
  c_3 &\equiv c_2 + 3 + p_3 \bmod 26 \equiv 16 + 3 + 2 \bmod 26 \equiv 19 \text { that is } T\\
  c_4 &\equiv c_3 + 3 + p_4 \bmod 26 \equiv 19 + 3 + 14 \bmod 26 \equiv 10 \text { that is } K\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me sir! You are a star! Just one question please, why or where did you get the following formula from: `ci=ci−1+3+pimod26`? I just want to understand the logic or reasoning as to how to derive the formula or where you get it from, thats all :). Otherwise, it makes sense

Comment: So I take it that the `+3 mod 26` would be in the block cipher bit and then you just add the value of the plaintext so like `11` for `L`? Genius sir, how do you know such formulas like is there a book explaining this at least? Another thing, say if I use a `IV` say `H` = 7 but I don't tell you the `IV` value - could you still decrypt my ciphertext??

Comment: I don't know where you can find in book, maybe in some exerciese. IV's are normally send unencrypted and there is no secuirty problems there. See, CBC and CTR mode of operations. This encryption, CFB Caesar is not secure. Within seconds a computer can show you all possible plaintext under the total IV's. IV's aim is randomizing the encryption to prevent the same plaintext get the same encryption.

Comment: Just out of interest, are there any softwares that allow me to experiment with this `CFB Caesar mode`? You know if any other formulas could be used to generate such ciphertexts? I just want to visually see it all

Comment: I accepted your answer BTW :).

Comment: @BenzaJackpuut Concentrate on modern Cryptology. Caesar cipher shown in the classrooms since 1) historical value 2) you can break it without knowing anything about plaintext - ciphertext-only attack.